# Stop Ubuntu changing output device without permission

Tags: 20.04, sound, pulseaudio

Since updating to Ubuntu 20.04 I have an issue where Ubuntu will change my output device seemingly randomly, other times it completely ignores my manual changes to the selected output device and switches back as soon as I close the settings.

I have seen [similar questions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1238000/ubuntu-20-04-change-sound-output-device-issue) about this but they just recommend `pavucontrol` which for me has not changed anything regarding this issue and I cannot comment asking about alternatives.

If anyone knows anything or even has a link to an open bug report about it that would be great.

Kind Regards