Audio Output Devices all wrong after using OBS
I have been experimenting with OBS Studio 30.1.2 flatpak on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. I don't really know what I'm doing, so I'm just playing around. I have definitely set up some PulseAudio input/output capture sources.
The issue is that all my audio output is going to my desktop speakers. I have set my headphones as the output device in Ubuntu sound settings, but the audio is going to the desktop speakers instead. Even when you do an audio test with the headphones selected as the output device, it's the desktop speakers that say "front left" and "front right".
So something is sending the audio to the wrong place. I have tried rebooting, connecting the heaphones to a different USB port, and even uninstalling the OBS flatpak. Issue persists.
I do get headphone audio when using OBS, so it's definitely something in there.
Any idea how to kill any custom OBS audio changes?

Solved by deleting pulseaudio user config and rebooting: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1238000/ubuntu-20-04-change-sound-output-device-issue
