# Sound problems after installing ubuntu 20.04 from scratch (no input and no output devices)

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, 20.04, hdmi

I've installed ubuntu on my new Dell G3 and I can't make sound work. Usually after installation/update I tackle these things but this time I'm kinda stuck.

Initially after installation I saw only "dummy output" in my output devices and nothing in input devices.

I've already looked into these:

[Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230363/20-04-internal-speaker-audio-is-not-working-in-ubuntu-20-04-lts-after-upgradi)

[And here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231602/no-sound-ubuntu-20-04-lts)

[And here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029502/no-audio-on-ubuntu-18-04)

I've tried to reinstall pulseaudio and reload alsa:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall alsa-base pulseaudio 
sudo alsa force-reload
```

After it did not help I also tried

```
alsactl restore
```

which gave me the following output:

```
alsactl: state_lock:125: file /var/lib/alsa/asound.state lock error: File exists
alsactl: load_state:1683: Cannot open /var/lib/alsa/asound.state for reading: File exists
Found hardware: "HDA-Intel" "Nvidia Generic" "HDA:10de0099,10280949,00100100" "0x1028" "0x0949"
Hardware is initialized using a generic method
```

This is output of "inxi -SMA":

```
System:
  Host: beautiful-creature Kernel: 5.4.0-31-generic x86_64 bits: 64 
  Desktop: Gnome 3.36.2 Distro: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (Focal Fossa) 
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: Dell product: G3 3590 v: N/A 
  serial: <superuser/root required> 
  Mobo: Dell model: 061RYD v: A00 serial: <superuser/root required> 
  UEFI: Dell v: 1.8.0 date: 11/11/2019 
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Cannon Lake PCH cAVS driver: sof-audio-pci 
  Device-2: NVIDIA TU116 High Definition Audio driver: snd_hda_intel 
  Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.4.0-31-generic
```

and output of "lspci | grep Audio":

```
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation TU116 High Definition Audio `Controller (rev a1)`
```

pavucontrol did not help to understand anything either. After all manipulations I've got "HDMI / DisplayPort - TU116 High Definition Audio COntroller" as the only option in Output device and nothing appeared in Input Devices. Headset does not add any device.

Help me, please. What do I miss?

Answer (score 1):

I have same situation on ubuntu 18.04 sound work, after install (not update) 20.04 - no sound devices - usb / pci build in, hdmi all ignored