# Ubuntu 20 plays bongo sound in headset at login then no sound on system once logged in

Tags: pulseaudio, 20.04, alsa

I am having no luck in getting sound once I'm logged into a session on my Ubuntu machine.

I have tried the suggestions within the post below:

[No sound - Ubuntu 20.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231602/no-sound-ubuntu-20-04-lts)

I have also tried all the solutions in:

https://itsfoss.com/fix-sound-ubuntu-1304-quick-tip/

pavucontrol gives me the following message:

[image: Volume control]

inxi -SMA gives me:

```
System:
  Host: JME Kernel: 5.4.0-31-generic x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: Gnome 3.36.2 
  Distro: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (Focal Fossa) 
Machine:
  Type: Desktop Mobo: ASUSTeK model: H110M-R v: Rev X.0x 
  serial: <superuser/root required> UEFI: American Megatrends v: 3401 
  date: 03/20/2017 
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel 100 Series/C230 Series Family HD Audio 
  driver: snd_hda_intel 
  Device-2: AMD Cedar HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 5400/6300/7300 Series] 
  driver: snd_hda_intel 
  Device-3: GN Netcom Jabra Link 370 type: USB 
  driver: jabra,snd-usb-audio,usbhid 
  Device-4: Logitech Webcam C270 type: USB driver: snd-usb-audio,uvcvideo 
  Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.4.0-31-generic
```

I see the following in the sound settings

[image]

this is a fresh upgrade from Ubuntu 18. And, just in case, yes I have tried muting/unmuting my headset; repeatedly!

Comment: Plug out your headphones, then plug them back in.

Comment: tried removing the USB connection and reinserting (it's bluetooth) but no joy. tried audio headphones in the jack and nothing either.

Comment: This morning, for reasons unknown it is working. It may be something to do with the NoMachine server the build is running. I'm getting some odd behaviour in the latest release of Ubuntu with nomachine. Once I got a remote instance running via a nomachine client on another box I started to see a Dummy input in the remote screen. Logging back onto the physical machine  I could see the JABRA headset... NoMachine seems to only run on a reboot right now (for others with similar woes)