# Jack port not detected

Tags: command-line, sound, 20.04, pulseaudio, alsa

I've been using Ubuntu 20.04 on a dual boon computer for a few months, but there's a thing that annoys me since the first day.

I have two jack ports on my PC, in one of which there are my headphones and the other one my speakers.

While they both work on Windows, whenever I use Ubuntu the latter one does not work anymore. It gets detected, but it acts as if it was mute.

If I try to switch the output, the speaker starts working, so the problem is related to the jack port and not the speaker itself.

I've tried every single suggestion of [this topic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132440/headphone-jack-not-working), [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231602/no-sound-ubuntu-20-04-lts) and a lot more, but nothing changed.

Inside pavucontrol I can find both the Ports and they are both marked as *plugged in*.

They are located under *Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio COntroller Analog Stereo*, where I can choose between the two ports.

Any suggestions apart from a factory reset? I'm getting crazy.

Thank you in advance for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by opening `alsamixer` from the terminal and switching the *Channel* setting from *2ch* to *6ch*. It suddenly started working with no need to restart my pc.