# installed Ubuntu no sound and dummy output

Tags: sound

I installed Ubuntu 21.04 on my Acer laptop and everything is working fine except for the sound. There is also a dummy output. I have tried many different solutions from the web but nothing seems to work. Card is there  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21).
I was so happy to finally get Ubuntu please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have HDMI output on this laptop, an HDMI cable, and a TV that accepts HDMI signals?

If so, then you might try this:

https://www.premitel.uk/consultancy/expert-advice/how-do-i-activate-the-hdmi-cable-connection-from-my-acer-laptop-to-my-tv/

Answer (score 0):

thank you
I found this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rqwdlkld9Ck
that together with this site. But I don't know if both helped or just the video.
[No sound - Ubuntu 20.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231602/no-sound-ubuntu-20-04-lts)

Comment: Sometimes just exercising the different output options for video and sound can unlock the modes that can help bring things back to normal.  I'm glad that you're on a happy path.